# Django CustomUser model Image field display in User List

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

`UserProfile` is CustomUser Model having columns avatar, bio and display fields.

I want to show Profile avatar in the User List

I have added avatar_tag function to be called by the users list

```py
#models.py
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    
    user   = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    
    
    def get_upload_avatar_to(self, filename):
        return f"images/avatar/{self.user.id}/{filename}"
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_upload_avatar_to, null=True, blank=True)

    def avatar_tag(self):
        if self.avatar.url is not None:
            return mark_safe('<img src="{}" height="50"/>'.format(self.avatar.url))
        else:
            return ""
    avatar_tag.short_description = 'Image'
    avatar_tag.allow_tags = True
    full_name = ''
   
    bio    = models.TextField(default="", blank=True)
    display    = models.CharField(default=full_name,max_length=512,blank=True)
```

admin.py code is below

```py
class UserProfileInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = UserProfile
    fk_name = 'user'
    can_delete = False
    verbose_name = "User profile"
    verbose_name_plural = 'Profiles'
    classes = ('text-capitalize','collapse open')
    extra = 1
    list_display = ('avatar_tag')
    fieldsets =  (
        ("Profile", {'fields': ('avatar','bio', 'display',)}),)


class UserProfileAdmin(UserAdmin):
    inlines = (UserProfileInline,)
```

How can I show the avatar image in list view of the User table?

I am not  getting any errors in the user list avatar is not shown

Here is the image
[image]

Comment: what's the question?

Comment: I want to show the avatar image in the list view of the user table

Comment: and what's is the error shown by the console?

Comment: I am not getting any error

Comment: In the list it is not shown

Comment: Try to move the function that return the html and list_display = ('avatar_tag', ) inside in the `UserProfileAdmin` class

Comment: I get an error <class 'df_chat.admin.UserProfileAdmin'>: (admin.E108) The value of 'list_display[0]' refers to 'avatar_tag', which is not a callable, an attribute of 'UserProfileAdmin', or an attribute or method on 'auth.User'.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253697/discussion-between-b-l-praveen-and-lorenzo-prodon).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code

```py
from django.utils.html import format_html


class UserProfileAdmin(UserAdmin):
    list_display = ("avatar_tag",) # pass other fileds if you want eg. name

    def avatar_tag(self, obj):
        if obj.userprofile.avatar:
            return format_html(
                '<img src="%s"/>' % obj.userprofile.avatar.url
            )
        return "No avatar"
```

[`list_display`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display) accepts callable argument so you can pass custom method names in it.

Comment: I get an error `'User' object has no attribute 'avatar'`

Comment: Hello @BLPraveen Does you user or **CustomUser** model contain `avatar` attribute?

Comment: I modified the code . How can we call class function in variable